# Using Perl Xml Module - append value in xml file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig, xml-libxml, xml-simple

File: SN.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <category name="Cat1" id="C1">
        <subcat name="SCName1" sid="SC1">
            <prod pname='prod1' pid='p1'></prod>
            <prod pname='prod2' pid='p2'></prod>
            <prod pname='prod3' pid='p3'></prod>
        </subcat>
    </category>

</root>
```

I want below output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
        <category name="Cat1" id="C1">
            <subcat name="SCName1" sid="SC1">
                <prod pname='prod1' pid='p1'></prod>
                <prod pname='prod2' pid='p2'></prod>
                <prod pname='prod3' pid='p3'></prod>
              **<prod pname='prod4' pid='p4'></prod>**
            </subcat>
        </category>

    </root>
```

Please help me to get this ouptput using modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using which module? Maybe you could identify which module you want to use? Also, http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: Hi Gideon I have tried xml-twig & xml-simple but the stuck in search under Category and then under Subcat.

Comment: adding what you tried into the question will (1) help people understand the problem better. (2) Encourage people to actually answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open SN.xml ;
$p := insert element prod append /root/category/subcat ;
set $p/@pname 'prod4' ;
set $p/@pid   'prod4' ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Thanks choroba! if we are having another category name is "cat2" we need to map like  Cat1->SCName1->prod4

Comment: XML::LibXML works with XPath. Learn it: `/root/category[@name="Cat1"]/subcat`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use XML::DOM to append value in subcat element.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::DOM;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);

my $str = <<F;
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <category name="Cat1" id="C1">
        <subcat name="SCName1" sid="SC1">
            <prod pname='prod1' pid='p1'></prod>
            <prod pname='prod2' pid='p2'></prod>
            <prod pname='prod3' pid='p3'></prod>
        </subcat>
    </category>
</root>
F

my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile();
print $fh $str;
close $fh;

my $parser = XML::DOM::Parser->new;
my $doc = $parser->parsefile($filename);

unlink $filename;

my $subcat = $doc->getElementsByTagName('subcat')->item(0);
my $prod =  $doc->createElement('prod');
$prod->setAttribute(pname=>'prod4');
$prod->setAttribute(pid=>'p4');
$subcat->appendChild($prod);
print $doc->toString;

__END__
```

This gives output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <category name="Cat1" id="C1">
        <subcat name="SCName1" sid="SC1">
            <prod pname="prod1" pid="p1"/>
            <prod pname="prod2" pid="p2"/>
            <prod pname="prod3" pid="p3"/>
        <prod pname="prod4" pid="p4"/></subcat>
    </category>
</root>
```

**Note!** As you may see there is a little problem with indentation and I don't know how to quickly fix it.